# Jest Testing React Class Component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm struggling to find a clear explanation to how to use jest to test a class react component. I want to add a unit test to an onSubmit function of a create form.

```
handleCreateHouse(e) {
        store.dispatch(createHouseDraft(this.state.house)).then(() => {
            if (!this.props.creation_error) {
                if (this.props.house.id) {
                    for (let key in this.floors) {
                        if (this.floors[key]) {
                            store.dispatch(createFloorDraft({ 'name': this.floors[key], 'house_id': this.props.house.id }))
                                .catch(err => console.log(err));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                switch (this.props.creation_error.code) {
                    case "duplicated_rif": {
                        this.setState({
                            ...this.state,
                            errors: {
                                ...this.state.errors,
                                ref: true
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }).then(() => store.dispatch(fetchHouseDraftList(this.state)))
        .then(() => this.props.onAddHouse())
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is a very broad question, I'm taking a stab at a very general idea around demystifying components and testing. React class components are at a very basic level plain JavaScript classes. So, for instance, you can test them out just like you'd test a class:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  handleCreateHouse(event) {
    this.setState({ clicked: true });
  }
}

const component = new MyComponent();
const setStateMock = jest.fn();
component.setState = setStateMock;
component.handleCreateHouse();
expect(setStateMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I wouldn't suggest doing this, though since most of your tests will end up taking a lot of mock setup that may not be that useful. More maintaining strategies could be:

1. use a test component-renderer like [enzyme](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme) or [react-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library). There may be many others, so I'm leaving the research to you.

These modules provide a way to instantiate a component and provide an API around this component that resembles functions like that of regular DOM. So you can trigger a state change, or a click on an element, check for various mocks to have been called, or perhaps even verify state changes.

2. Try to factor the callbacks to have as much "stateless" code as possible: in the example you provided, if you ignore the `this.state` access/setter, most of the code is logic which can be tested without actually setting up the component harness. This then becomes similar to the example I showed above.

---

Another area of confusion might arise with `store`. This seems like a magic object that's available in the function's context. It's not clear where the object is coming from—my guess is that the store is created in the same file that hosts the component, which I'd say is a bit non-traditional. If that's the case, you can choose to mock the store implementation (but still reuse actions you have in your app) using `redux-mock-store`; this library is used in the [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'm going to do a little bit of research